# Failed to remove attachment in Thunderbird AddOn

Tags: attachment, xul, thunderbird-addon

I try to remove a particular attachment which I know his path in var `SomeAddOnName.MessengerCompose.filePathCurrent` with the following instructions :

```
    //Construct reference attachment
    var fileAttachmentBefore = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
    fileAttachmentBefore.initWithPath(SomeAddOnName.MessengerCompose.filePathCurrent);
    var attachmentBefore = FileToAttachment(fileAttachmentBefore);
    //Remove attachment
    gMsgCompose.compFields.removeAttachment(attachmentBefore);
```

but It doesn't work and `gMsgCompose.compFields.attachments` is still empty, whatever I do in mail composer.

Do anyone know what I must do ?

Thanks